# Finding a maximum in inverse parabola iteratively

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have an array that represents an inverse parabola and I want to find the maximum which can be anywhere in the array. In my application I cannot take the derivative and I have to loop through the array.
I implemented this by iterating through the array starting on the left and until I get a value lower that the previous iteration:

```
import numpy as np 

def simulation(n):
    # create inverse parabola
    num = 21
    parabola= np.linspace(-8, 12, num=num)
    parabola= -np.abs(parabola) ** 2
    return parabola[n]


previous_iteration = -1000 # some initialization
for n in range(num):

    # Configure the entire system
    # Run simulation

    # simulation(n) - a function returning simulation result with configuration "n"
    simulation_result = simulation(n)

    if previous_iteration < simulation_result :
        previous_iteration = simulation_result 
    else:
        best_iteration = n-1
        break

print(best_iteration)
print(previous_iteration)
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Edit:
The actual implementation will be on a FPGA and for every iteration I have to configure the system and run a simulation so every iteration costs a lot of time. If I run the simulation with all possible configurations, I will get a parabola vector but that will be time consuming and very inefficient.
Im looking for a way to find the maximum value while generating as less points as possible. Unfortunately the for loop has to stay because that is representation of how the system works. The key here is to change the code inside the for loop.
I edited the code to better explain what I mean.

Comment: For speed, you could use `parabola.max()`, but the iteration is hidden

Comment: It is unclear whether you want the maximum value of the parabola, or the argument that yields the maximum value.

Comment: James: the implementation will be on an FPGA so im looking for an algorithm. Kefeng91: I want the argument

Comment: what about using differences instead of derivatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inverse parabola (sampled at evenly spaced points) has the property that the differences between adjacent points always decreases. The maximum is just before the differences go negative.

If the difference between the first two points is negative or zero, the maximum is the first point in the array.

Otherwise, do a binary search to find the smallest positive difference between two adjacent points. The maximum will be the second of these two points.

Comment: Thanks for your answear Paul but that is basically what I do except that I compare the results and not subtract them. Because it is very costly for me to "look" at every point, I am looking for a way to find the maximum while "looking" on as little points as possible.

Comment: You don't do a binary search, you do a linear scan.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I will use what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called a grid search. You need to define your search grid points (here in 'x') and calculate all the values of the parabola for these points (here in 'y'). You can use np.argmax to find the index of the argument that yields the maximum value:

```
import numpy as np

# Define inverse parabola
parabola = lambda x: -np.abs(x)**2

# Search axis
x = np.linspace(-8, 12, 21)

# Calculate parabola at each point
y = parabola(x)

# Find argument that yields maximum value
xmax = x[np.argmax(y)]
print(xmax)           # Should be 0.0
```

Comment: Kefeng91 thank you for the answear but I may not explained myself very well. I edited the post hopefully the problem clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the post hopefully the problem clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a "ternary search": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search

It works to find the maximum of any function **f(x)** that has an increasing part, maybe followed by an all-equal part, followed by a decreasing part.

Given bounds **low** and **high**, pick 2 points **m1 = low +(high-low)/3** and **m2 = low + (high-low)*2/3**.

Then if **f(m1) > f(m2)**, you know the maximum is at **x<=m2**, because **m2** can't be on the increasing part.  So set **high=m2** and try again.

Otherwise, you know the maximum is at **x>=m1**, so set **low=m1** and try again.

repeat until **high-low < 3** and then just pick whichever of those values is biggest.